# I was trying to reinstall Eclipse and an unexpected error showed up

Tags: java, eclipse

So I was trying to reinstall Eclipse through the installer.previously removed the folders (that's what I read on how to uninstall it) and a problem showed up.

I was trying to remove Eclipse and removed all the folders (searched "eclipse" in my disk and deleted it all). And now while reinstalling it through the installer this showed up.

Don't know what to do so anything helps.

> [2020-03-23 22:43:56] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:550)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:342)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:903)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3827)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3755)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3736)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3629)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1342)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1204)
>     at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1149)
>     ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Garrido_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
>     ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
>     java.io.IOException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\Garrido.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.core_3.5.700.v20191221-1203.jar
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:340)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:546)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:342)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:903)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3827)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3755)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3736)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3629)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1342)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1204)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1149)
>     Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Garrido.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.core_3.5.700.v20191221-1203.jar
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198)
>       at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843)
>       at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1172)
>       at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:718)
>       at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:238)
>       at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:168)
>       at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:182)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:322)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:546)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:342)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:903)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3827)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3755)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3736)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3629)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1342)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1204)
>       ... 1 more

---

I already tried to execute the installer as admin and the same error showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message appears to be the result of some mirrored repositories lacking the files required for installing Eclipse.

All the changes the installer made should have been rolled back automatically, so here's how to avoid the issue:

1) Relaunch the installer;

2) Click the hamburger menu in the upper right corner of the installer window;

3) Select Advanced Mode (you can choose to save the installer in a permanent location if you want);

4) On the first page, make sure you've selected the Eclipse package you want installed and click next;

5) Check off any projects you want to provision and click next;

6) Make sure your install destination folder name is correct and click next;

7) At the bottom left of the final window are three small checkboxes. You should uncheck the "Mirrors" checkbox and click Finish.

Turning off mirrors ensures that your Eclipse download comes straight from the eclipse.org download servers rather than a potentially incomplete mirror. Your install should proceed without issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quck answer! It didn´t work only with that becouse it seems that I had some broken plugins so at the "Analyze feature for p2 pools"or something like that I analyzed them and then repaired it!